# Optimizing a MySQL Query with subqueries in it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to optimize this query below to make it more efficient and stop loading slow. Can someone please show me what I would need to be doing to optimize this for future references.

```
SELECT * , username AS user, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pvp WHERE killer = user) AS kills, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pvp WHERE username = user) AS deaths, 
ROUND(kills / deaths, 2) AS kd FROM stats WHERE username =  "Username"
```

Comment: If you have kills and deaths in stats, why get the data from pvp?

Comment: I dont? It doesnt say it does. Read it over again dude.

Comment: `ROUND(kills / deaths, 2) AS kd FROM stats`

Comment: (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pvp WHERE killer = user) AS kills, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pvp WHERE username = user) AS deaths,

Comment: I said re-read it. It gets kill & deaths from the other pvp database.

Comment: _for future references_ the reason your query is slow is because for every row in `stats` it makes two passes through `pvp` to provide the `COUNT(*)`. An optimal solution will minimise these passes through the `pvp` table (perhaps to a single pass), as well as make a single pass through the main `kd` table.

Comment: there is no kd table. re-read the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *,pvptable.username As user,COUNT(pvptable.killer) as kills,
COUNT(pvptable.username) as deaths,
ROUND(COUNT(pvptable.killer) / COUNT(pvptable.username), 2) AS kd FROM stats as st
LEFT JOIN pvp as pvptable ON pvptable.killer='user' 
AND pvptable.username='user' WHERE st.username="Username";
```

Comment: I get this error 
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN pvp as pvptable ON pvptable.killer=user AND pvptable.username=user LE' at line 4`

Comment: No it is not solved. I get the error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN pvp as pvptable ON pvptable.killer="jackfrost" AND pvptable.username=' at line 4`

Comment: I changed your code to `select *,username As user,COUNT(pvptable.killer) as kills,
COUNT(pvptable.username) as deaths,
ROUND(COUNT(pvptable.killer) / COUNT(pvptable.username), 2) AS kd  FROM stats
LEFT JOIN pvp as pvptable ON pvptable.killer='user' 
AND pvptable.username='user' LEFT JOIN stats as sc ON sc.username="Username"` because you didnt add a "FROM stats" before the left join. Just was testing it idk if that is correct or not but,  now im getting the follwing error `Column 'username' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: I have changes Query Please check then after give me Feedback

Comment: Alright so it runs the query just fine but it says 0 for kills & deaths from the `pvp` table it also says null for all the other rows from the `pvp` table that was joined.

Comment: This is the query im running I know that the username has rows in the `pvp` table and a row in the `stats` table.
`select *,pvptable.username As user,COUNT(pvptable.killer) as kills,
COUNT(pvptable.username) as deaths,
ROUND(COUNT(pvptable.killer) / COUNT(pvptable.username), 2) AS kd FROM stats as st
LEFT JOIN pvp as pvptable ON pvptable.killer="tacoboboy32"
AND pvptable.username="tacoboboy32" WHERE st.username="tacoboboy32";`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT username AS user, sum(kills) kills,sum(deaths) deaths FROM    
(
 select (SELECT CASE WHEN killer = user THEN 1 ELSE 0 END kills,
  CASE WHEN username = user THEN 1 ELSE 0 END deaths from pvp),
  ROUND(kills / deaths, 2) AS kd FROM stats 
) a
GROUP BY username
```

Comment: Ya forgot to add select in inner query try once and let me know. I don't have table structure so unable to run query.

Comment: it says `Unknown column 'user' in 'field list'`

Comment: You should pass your input value there.

Comment: I get the following error.
`Operand should contain 1 column(s)`